# Accept downloads automatically in Selenium WebDriver using IEDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-iedriver

How I can accept downloads in Selenium using InternetExplorerDriver.
Now when click to download file, Save As Dialog appears and then WebDriver stop the work.
 I try to search a capability to set this how in ChromeDriver is just only add `chromedriver.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);`

but I not found.

I need when driver click in button to download, the download automatically start and save in any folder.

Sorry my bad question. I'm new here.

Comment: Be specific about your question . Provide proper details

Comment: Seems that you want someone to write code for you. This is the wrong way to use StackOverflow. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to create good question and get good answer

Comment: Sorry my bad question. I try to improvement this question.

Comment: which language you are working on ? if java, I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have windows machine so i couldn't check this but try following article. There is a registry which you need to modify to get such behavior.  Let me know if it works. 
https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/

found another thread discussing the same thing
https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer